# Samba4 AD Time Sync

Tags: time, samba4

I know this question is asked a lot, and I've googled for days, but none of the solutions I have found so far work. My problem is this:

Windows 10 workstations are not syncing their time with my Samba4 domain controller.

I have verified that ntpd is running.  I have ntpd and domain policy configured as per this article:  https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Time_Synchronisation

When I run "net time /domain /set /Y" as administrator, the time synchronizes correctly, however automatic syncs don't work.

"w32tm /resync" returns: "https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Time_Synchronisation"

w32tm /query /status returns:

```
Leap Indicator: 3(last minute has 61 seconds)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified)
Precision: -23 (119.209ns per tick)
Root Delay: 0.0000000s
Root Dispersion: 0.0000000s
ReferenceId: 0x00000000 (unspecified)
Last Successful Sync Time: unspecified
Source: Local CMOS Clock
Poll Interval: 6 (64s)
```

w32tm /query /configuration returns:

```
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Policy)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Policy)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 6 (Policy)
MaxPollInterval: 10 (Policy)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Policy)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Policy)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Policy)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Policy)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Policy)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Policy)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Policy)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Policy)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Policy)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Policy)
UpdateInterval: 100 (Policy)

FileLogName: c:\temp\time_debug.log (Local)
FileLogEntries: 0-300 (Local)
FileLogSize: 100000 (Local)

[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
CrossSiteSyncFlags: 2 (Policy)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Policy)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Policy)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 0 (Policy)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Policy)
Type: NT5DS (Policy)
```

I am at a loss as to where to look.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a similar answer over at [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1690262/225775). In short, we fixed it by adding the correct `ntpsigndsocket` line in `/etc/ntp.conf`:

```
ntpsigndsocket  /var/lib/ntp_signd/
```

The socket path can be determined via:

```
% sudo lsof -Un | grep signd
samba       525            root   23u  unix 0x0000000029f51b41      0t0 15061 /var/lib/samba/ntp_signd/socket type=STREAM
```

We fixed the windows member by stopping the time provider service, re-registering it and restarting the service again:

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
```

The domain controller should then be shown with `w32tm /query /source`.

Credit and Kudos go to the user `mfoley` at [LinuxQuestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/ntp-on-samba-4-dc-not-syncing-with-windows-10-workstations-4175685516/#post6187657). Thx!